# Google Storage API - Retrieve object with "/" in name

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I try to retrieve an object with a "/" in the name I get all of the file information and metadata in the response, but the link to the file itself just points to "not found".  This applies to both in my code, and using the API Explorer on their website.

For example, a file named "testfolder/test.txt". It shows up in the Developer Console correctly as a pseudo-folder named "testfolder/" and a file inside named "test.txt", but when do a Get on "testfolder/test.txt", or List with prefix of "testfolder/" I run into the issue mentioned above.

I can retrieve the object file fine in gsutil and from the console. I can also retrieve the object file fine with the API if I use a symbol other than "/".  It's just something about the "/" causing the link from the API response to not point to the file correctly.

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dschaffertestbucket/o/testfolder%2Ftest.txt?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
200 OK  
{

 "kind": "storage#object",
 "id": "dschaffertestbucket/testfolder/test.txt/1429992872601000",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/dschaffertestbucket/o/testfolder%2Ftest.txt",
 "name": "testfolder/test.txt",
 "bucket": "dschaffertestbucket",
 "generation": "1429992872601000",
 "metageneration": "1",
 "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
 "updated": "2015-04-25T20:14:32.600Z",
 "storageClass": "STANDARD",
 "size": "14",
 "md5Hash": "vLrQ6JkgmdfYKJKKN1ebFQ==",
 "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dschaffertestbucket/o/testfolder%2Ftest.txt?generation=1429992872601000&alt=media",
 "owner": {
  "entity": "user-00b4903a971fb6d48e9e442442b7892dfc55f81ce026106122cb58989d926f00",
  "entityId": "00b4903a971fb6d48e9e442442b7892dfc55f81ce026106122cb58989d926f00"
 },
 "crc32c": "Qcfj8Q==",
 "etag": "CKjLz8miksUCEAE="
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about the exact problem? Can you drop in a text version of both your request payload and the response payload with the bad link?

Comment: Retrieving an object that has a forward slash in the name is no different from retrieving any other object (except on the dev console UI where psuedo-folders are shown). If you are able to retrieve objects without slashes you should be able to retrieve objects with slashes. Could you do as Chris suggested and post your request/respone payloads (scrub the auth headers first).

Comment: Updated with request/response.

Answer (score -2):

In this [article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) you can find that Cloud Storage doesn't have a file hierarchy like Windows and Linux, and that 'gsutil' and Cloud Storage APIs simply give the illusion of one.

In your case it would be easier to just avoid including the "/" character in your file names, or use a different character instead.